# how to load values (users and users_profiles) to a database upon application start?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

In my application, I have a file called `HibernateConfiguration.java` that has the main database configuration and using the code excerpt bellow I manage to create the tables upon the application start:

```
   private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;        
    }
```

Now I'd like to populate some tables upon start after they are created by Hibernate. Currently I have to run a sql script to populate `USER_PROFILE` and `USER` before accessing the application.

How to do it in Spring? I'm using it without XMLs files to configure everything.

Comment: I would use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto and set it to create or update.

Comment: just be aware that don't use this one in production :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like populate tables upon start, simplest way is using of `@PostConstruct` annotation. Actually, you can mark with it method of configuration, but I would I prefer to create separate bean:

```
public class DataInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void populate(){
        User user = new User();
        //set user props ...
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Now just register this component into configuration (or mark this class with `@Component` if you use component scan):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{
    ...

    @Bean
    public DataInitializer createDataInitializer(){
        return new DataInitializer();
    }
}
```

I don't know do you use JPA repositories, or not. But if you work with `EntityManager` directly, be note, that you cant use `@Transactional` annotation on `@PostConstruct`. In this case you have to use `TransactionTemplate`:

```
public class DataInitializer {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager txManager;


    @PostConstruct
    public void populate(){

        TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
        template.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                User user = new User();
                //set user props ...
                manager.merge(user);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Same way you can do, if you work with Hibernate session.